Laravel reporting error in Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded even with max_execution_time in 300
I'm using PHP 8.2.12 and Laravel 9.52.16, and even setting max_execution_time to 300, restarting XAMPP, and restarting the computer, if the project takes more than 60 seconds to load, the maximum execution time error occurs. How do I fix this?
P.S.: I'm using a localhost project

2 thoughts: Are you sure that this isn't changed somewhere in your project? Are you sure that you have adjusted the correct php ini file?

Run phpinfo() through Laravel and check: 1) What INI files are parsed 2) What values for max_execution_time are reported.


Set excution_time  at PHP config file
Set excution_time at Xampp server
Sometimes your brower will close automatically when request take time is too long -> use curl, postman to send request, or think about queue in laravel


You need to do more steps to figure out if it not working even after changing the MAX_EXECUTION_TIME value.

As you are using Laravel so use the following code in your /routes/web.php file:

Route::get('/phpinfo', function () {
    return phpinfo();
});

Then, test this above added route like (modify it according to your url and port:
http://locahost:8000/phpinfo


Look for the "Loaded Configuration File" to confirm the active php.ini path and change the value of

max_execution_time = 300

After you have done the changes in php.ini file, you must restart your XAMPP server.

To identify the active value of max_execution_time use the following code:

dd(ini_get('max_execution_time'));



The Apache server might have a timeout configuration that overrides PHP's max_execution_time. You need to locate your Apache configuration file according to your operating system

Windows:
xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf 

or
xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

Search for the Timeout directive and set it to a higher value:
Timeout 300

Also restart Apache.
The above steps will help you to fix this MAX_EXECUTION_TIME issue.

I did exactly as described and it didn't work, after 60 seconds PHP reports the error Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded.
This only started happening after updating PHP to version 8.2.12, is it a bug in this version?

Install WAMMP or LARAGON and test with that. They have different settings and give you more control on your php settings.

@AlexandreSantosGomes This answer provides a list of steps to get diagnostic information, do you mean phpinfo() doesn't work or you didn't try?

@ÁlvaroGonzález I have performed all the steps on the list, but the error continues to occur when the execution exceeds 60 seconds. phpinfo() displays the value I set for max_execution_time, but it is still not respected. I can work normally, but I can't open some heavier reports on localhost.

Might be some other php server is running. Can you go to the command prompt and type 'php -v' and check whether it matches with the php version which is shown in phpinfo()

@EshbanBahadur Is it reported as "Local Value" or as "Master Value"? Do you get matches if you look for max_execution_time or set_time_limit in your project files?
